# How to search for () { :; }; bash vulnerability pattern in many files?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, awk

I'm sure many people could benefit from having a way to search through files to look for the bash vulnerability pattern.

Comment: FYI, this example is merely a common, short way of showing the problem. Looking for it will not help you find exploited or exploitable files.

Comment: Indeed, it's not something that would be likely to show up in files **at all**. The exploit is carried out through environment variables.

Comment: I'd agree that what the grep below is really showing you is if you have a trojan.  Not really if you are exploitable.

Comment: This is to search for traffic log files to see anyone actually try to use the exploit against a service.

Comment: Best approach is to just update your version of bash.

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -R '\(\)\{ *: *;\}' *
```

Start in a directory and this will search for that pattern in all files going down recursively.

Comment: what if spacing is different ?

Comment: On the plus side, the string *must* begin with `() {` exactly; on the minus side, the contents of the script aren't the vulnerability; it's the environment when script is *run*. Search through the file will accomplish nothing.

Comment: As I mentioned above as well, the grep is really of limited use anyway as it really indicates a trojan file and nothing else.